# App not loading. Never ending Loop in oncreate method in initial activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My problem is since a recent change, my app is not loading anymore.
I have no exception, app doesn't crash, just not loading.
When I debug, I see my app is calling in loop onCreate....
I don't know why.
I've recently made a change in my SQLite management.

MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static DbHandler handler;
    ....
@Override
  public void onCreate()
  {
    super.onCreate();
    handler = new DbHandler(this);
  }

}

Class DbHandler(this)

    public class DbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myapp.db";

    public DbHandler(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        DatabaseManager.initializeInstance(this);

    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PdvHandler.TABLE_SHOP);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PdvHandler.TABLE_PROJECT);
        // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CAPTURE_INFO);
        db.execSQL(PdvHandler.CREATE_PDV_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        int upgradeTo = oldVersion + 1;
        while (upgradeTo <= newVersion) {
            switch (upgradeTo) {
            case 2:
                try{
                    db.execSQL(AlertaHandler.DROP_ALERT);
                    db.execSQL(AlertaHandler.CREATE_ALERT);                 
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Crashlytics.logException(e);
                }
                break;
            }
            upgradeTo++;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally DatabaseManager.java

```
public class DatabaseManager {
    private AtomicInteger mOpenCounter = new AtomicInteger();

    private static DatabaseManager instance;
    private static SQLiteOpenHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    public static synchronized void initializeInstance(SQLiteOpenHelper helper) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseManager();
        }
        mDatabaseHelper = helper;
    }

    public static synchronized DatabaseManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    DatabaseManager.class.getSimpleName()
                            + " is not initialized, call initializeInstance(..) method first.");
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public synchronized SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
        if (mOpenCounter.incrementAndGet() == 1) {
            // Opening new database
            mDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        return mDatabase;
    }

    public synchronized void closeDatabase() {
        if (mOpenCounter.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
            // Closing database
            mDatabase.close();

        }
    }
}
```

The problem must be in there, because it is what I have changed.
I just don't see what should happen so that the initial activity is called in a neverending loop ( onCreate in called in a neverending loop)

My Activity that is looping in onCreate

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
private Context ctx = null;
private Usuario mUser = null;
SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Crashlytics.start(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ctx = this;
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String activityName = getClass().getSimpleName().toString();
    prefs.edit().putString("FrontActivity", activityName).commit();

    }
}
```

EDIT: 
When I comment :

```
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                            LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
```

in my SplashScreen, it doesn't loop anymore
LoginActivity doesn't do nothing more than displaying login screen....

EDIT2:
I have a log in Crashlytics that I can't make the relation easily, but it might help

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.
 raw
android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel (InputChannel.java)
android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel (InputChannel.java:135)
android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.add (IWindowSession.java:523)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView (ViewRootImpl.java:664)
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView (WindowManagerImpl.java:326)
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView (WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView (WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView (Window.java:552)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:2684)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2122)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$700 (ActivityThread.java:134)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1218)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:4867)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

The problem is

Comment: Have you called the debugger and asked what he has to say?

Comment: isn't this your splash screen ? so it does absolutely nothing , just sets a preference ?How do you know its looping , did you print a log in onCreate ? Also why is your handler static ?

Comment: My debugger is the one that tell me that it is looping. And my splash screen do a lot of stuff. It sync my sqlite db with an external mysql db

Comment: I commented, all the sync operations, and it still is looping!